# How to view and add the prices depends from the clicked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

How can I view the price of the checked checkbox in the Total field. For example the user checked the Price 1 with the price of $20, the $20 will be added to the Total field automatically without refreshing the page and displays it. Then the user will also checked the Price 2 with the price of $30, then it will be added to the Total field. Then what if the user change his mind and uncheck the Price 2, the total price now will just contain the value of Price 1 which is $20.

If the user unchecked all the checked checkboxes, the total field must be zero because nothing is being selected. (No refreshing the page)

This is my html codes:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="$20"> Price 1 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="$30"> Price 2 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="$40"> Price 3 </br>
        </br></br>
        Total: <input type="text" name="total" disabled="true">

</form>
```

I don't know the codes for it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/master.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="$20"> Price 1 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="$30"> Price 2 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="$40"> Price 3 </br>
        </br></br>
        Total: <input type="text" name="total" disabled="true">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //bind the change event to the checkboxes
        $('input[name="checkbox1"]').change(function(){
            var total = 0;
            //get value from each selected ckeck box
            $('input[name="checkbox1"]:checked').each(function(){
                var tval = $(this).val();
                //remove $ sign from value
                //convert it to a flot
                //plus it to the total
                total += parseFloat(tval.replace("$",""));                
            });
            //finally display the total with a $ sign
            $('input[name="total"]').val("$ " + total);
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your codes works great! I also understands how it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

  updateTotal();

});

function updateTotal(){
  var total = 0;

  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){


       total += parseFloat($(this).val())

  })


  $('#total').val('$ '+total);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljovcz1y/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ":checkbox" ).on('change', function(){
   makeSum(); 
});

function makeSum(){
    var totalVal = 0;
    $( ":checked" ).each(function(index, checkbox){
          totalVal += parseInt($(checkbox).val(), 10);
    });
    $('input[name="total"]').val("$" + totalVal);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9fe9wonx/